# soundcloud html5 widget is not firing load progress event

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I am embedding a soundcloud player on my page and I want to listen to several events,
especially SC.Widget.Events.LOAD_PROGRESS,
but this one does not get fired while. PLAY_PROGRESS is working properly.
So why is LOAD_PROGRESS not being fired?

```
initSC: function () {
            var self = this;
            return  {
                play: function (id) {
                    var that = this;
                    if(this.player === null){
                    var iframeElement = document.querySelector('iframe');
                    this.player = SC.Widget(iframeElement);
                    }
                    if(self.sid === id && this.player !=null){
                        this.player.play();

                    }else{
                        var uri = "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + id;

                        this.player.load(uri, { callback: function () {
                            self.sid= id;
                            self.provider = "sc";
                            that.player.play();
                            that.player.getDuration(function (durationSC) {
                                self.duration = parseInt(durationSC) /1000;

                                self.setDuration(App.UTIL.millisecondsToMMss(durationSC));
                            });


                            that.player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
                                self.playerState = PLAYER_STATES.PLAYING;
                                console.log("sc starts playing");
                            });

                            that.player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, function (e) {
                                //currentPosition: 0
                                //loadedProgress: 0
                                //relativePosition: 0
                                self.setElapsedTime(App.UTIL.millisecondsToMMss(e.currentPosition));
                                self.setProgress(e.currentPosition/1000);
                            });


                        }});
                        that.player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.LOAD_PROGRESS, function (e) {
                            log(e);
                        });


                    }




                },
                player: null
            }
```

Regards,
Phil

Comment: Hey Phil, could you please put just the code you think's not working on JSbin or JSfiddle or the likes in order to isolate the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hi I am not able to isolate my code easily. But while I was doing some more investigations i stumbled upon this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gyuzz/10/  where the event is also not being fired. So this seems to be a general problem..

Comment: Might it be possible that a typo (LOAD_PROGRESS:"loadProgres" ), loadprogres with just one s, in https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js    is responsible for not being fired ?

Comment: any ideas? help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a bug and is now fixed and live, thanks for the detailed report. Please do note that we support range requests for HTML5 audio, which means that we consider the track to be fully loaded from the beginning.

For browsers that don’t support native mp3 playback, like Firefox, we will fall back to a Flash implementation in the background, which will trigger `LOAD_PROGRESS` events until fully loaded.

Comment: We had to rollback this deploy for other reasons. Will get back to you when it’s live again.

Comment: I am not sure whether your rollback was successful but I do get  lots of errors, e.g.

GET https://eventlogger.soundcloud.com/pageview?anonymous_id=119516-74329-20844…chapter=localhost%3A%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F13692671  widget-d06cf92c.js:37
GET https://eventlogger.soundcloud.com/pageview?anonymous_id=119516-74329-20844…

Comment: That seems to be something unrelated. It’s all good now and this fix is live again. Sorry for the delay.